# Difference between silicone grease and anti-seize?

Tags: grease, anti-seize

I have done front brake job - Disk (DIY) on my car. I have used anti-seize for brake contact points, back-side (metallic side) of brake pads, and for caliper guide pins - cleaned existing lube, then sprayed silicone spray around pin, after that I have applied thin layer of anti-seize around the pin and inserted back.

This is my first brake job (DIY). Just worried whether using anti-seize instead of grease on above locations would be a problem?

Comment: this post on reddit made me to ask this question

https://www.reddit.com/r/MechanicAdvice/comments/ag4uqo/psa_please_do_not_use_antiseize_on_brake_jobs/#:~:text=If%20you%20use%20it%20on,brake%20lubricant%2C%20use%20that%20instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anti-seize compounds should not be used on moving parts.

They generally contain fine metal particles like copper, or aluminium.  Grease used for lubrication would not want any particles in it that would cause wear.

Anti-sieze compounds containing soft metals like copper and aluminium will leave a layer of soft metal between the components, so even in a case where the grease has all gone and the components are rusty, there will still be the layer of soft metal that should  allow the components to separate.

Comment: do I needed to redo guide pins, removing Anti seize and applying silicon grease

Comment: can I use silicone lubricant spray instead of silicon grease?

Comment: I would redo them with the correct grease.

Answer (score 0):

Anti seize compound is used on O2 sensors to allow removal after hundreds of cold/heat cycles to prevent dissimilar metals from reacting to create corrosion resulting in seized threads. Other applications are for exposure to road salts that can create galvanic reaction resulting in seized hardware. This is not recommended for brake lube purposes. Brake grease is developed for lubrication and thick to prevent cooking and running off hot surfaces. Silicone spray will dry out, leaving bare metal to allow corrosion to occur, eventually seizing parts. If you choose to use personal methods not following recommended products for lubricating brake parts, you assume all risks of future problems. There are plenty of guidelines from recognized sources, brake shops, service manuals, and youtube videos to learn correct brake service. After all, you assume all risks in brake service. Why not follow established procedures?

Comment: understood. Thanks